# how to use external API for authentication wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can you please help on how to develop a wordpress plugin that utilizes the authenticate filter hook with external api for authentication

I tried the functions.php file but its not working

Comment: A good way to approach this problem is to study some of the open-source [external authentication plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/oauth+saml/). An answer to your question is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Can you add the code and see?